# Blogger search only showing 7 results

Tags: search, content-management-system, blogger

This is my blog: https://www.vapeupdeals.com

If i enter any search term it only shows 7 results. I am not sure why this must be happening?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities :

1. Your posts limit is set to 7
2. Your posts list exceeded the limit for auto-pagination feature (it's a hidden feature that Blogger never mentioned), that's it 50 `<img>` tag and the size of HTML page being requested in kilobytes which amount is not mentioned.

Here's the full article from official blog of Blogger from almost a decade ago :

https://blogger.googleblog.com/2010/02/auto-pagination-on-blogger.html

Comment: hey Bill, Thanks for your response. I checked the setting and the limit was set to 7, I increased the post limit but its not working. If you can provide me your gmail I can give you access, could you please check.

The second option is very less likely.

Comment: No, you don't need to. Just edit every posts that have more than 1 image and give your post a **more** tag (by clicking on more button on the toolbar) after the first paragraph or image of your post.